# Pointwise convergence vs. almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I do not understand the difference between these two types of convergence for random variables. Actually, I am not seeing a lot of people using the notion of pointwise convergence for random variables.

So, what is the difference? Does anyone have a memorable example illustrating the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions $f_n:X\to\mathbb R$, where $X$ is some measure space with measure $\mu$. Let $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be another measurable function.

The sequence $\{f_n\}$ **converges to $f$ pointwise** if for each $x\in X$, the sequence of real numbers $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$. Notice that this doesn't use the measure $\mu$ at all.

The sequence $\{f_n\}$ **converges to $f$ almost everywhere** (or **almost surely**, or **pointwise almost everywhere**, etc.) if there is a subset $B\subset X$ with $\mu(B)=0$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ pointwise on $X\setminus B$. Observe that pointwise convergence implies a.e. convergence by taking $B=\varnothing$.

An example to illustrate the difference. Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on the unit interval $[0,1]$ with the standard Lebesgue measure. Then $f_n\to 0$ almost everywhere since, if $x\neq 1$, then $x^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, so that we can take $B=\{1\}$ in the definition of a.e. convergence. However, $f_n\not\to 0$ pointwise since $f_n(1)=1\neq 0$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thank you. So, by taking the same example, it will convergence pointwise to $0$ if you consider the interval $[0,1[$? 
But one thing I do not understand, in a probabilistic point of view, is pointwise convergence really something relevant? In fact, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is converging to the function $f$ expect at (finite?) zero point measures.

Comment: 1: Yes, that's correct. 2: Not really. When people say pointwise convergence in measure theory or probability, they almost always (get it?) mean a.e. convergence.

Comment: When one says a random variable, say Yn converges a.s. to Y (e.g., strong law of large numbers, Yn = sample mean, Y = population mean < \infty), is that equivalent to saying the probability density/mass function of the random variable |Yn-Y| pointwise converges to the dirchilet function (all mass on 0)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence) convergence of random variables $X_n$ to $X$ almost surely is

$$ m \{\ t\ | \lim_n\  X_{n}(t) = X(t)\} = 1 $$

Here $m$ is the underlying probability measure, and I interpret $X_n(t)$, $X(t)$ as the probability density functions (probability mass functions if $m$ is discrete).

So I think $X_n\to X$ a.s. is just pointwise convergence of their pdfs/pmfs.